# Lists with sections / style lists like preferences

Tags: android, android-layout

Im trying to achieve the following:

http://www.izujar.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/carbon.jpg

As you can see in the right screenshoot, you can see a window like a PreferenceScreen, is this really a PreferenceScreen or is styled? What I want to put inside the "sections" are custom views not the PreferenceScreen ones. Is there any native component to create this or is the developer who needs to style this "lists"? Also I see in the developer android portal the following: https://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/lists.html This is what I want but I dont find the control.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any native component to create this

`ListView` can handle this, as `ListView` is what the preference system uses.

The key is in what you hand to the `ListView` as your adapter, as the adapter will need to handle your section headings in addition to the rest of the rows. [My `MergeAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) can help with this, and there are other adapter implementations offering sections available as open source as well.

Comment: So there is no native componenet to achieve this, we need to use a custom adapter + style views for get similar effects, isnt it? Then I think google needs to change a little the developer guide since I think when I read it there is something to do this.(https://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/lists.html)Thanks.